# How to compare key management strategies

Tags: cryptography, key-management

Are there formal security definitions or frameworks to evaluate the quality of a key management scheme? Can I state something like "the key is *XYZ-protected* against a polynomial adversary given that [constraint] holds"? Or "that solution has a *key exposure factor* of 0.72"?

For example, I can intuitively see that a key that is secret shared has *better* protection than a key that is not (because, for a threshold *t*, *t* shares would need to be compromised to calculate the key). Or that a key inside an HSM is harder to retrieve than a key in a plaintext file in a PC. But *how harder*?

**How can I objectively argue that a control is critical to protect the key** (or the opposite: that discarding a specific control is acceptable in a scenario)?

I realize that a definitive answer will depend on the threat model and the risks that could be accepted, but **I wonder if there are terms and parameters that can be used to compare alternatives.**

Comment: There are several well-known standards, security policies, regulations for crypto-graphic key management. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: My general idea is that pretty much every cryptographic algorithm is proven secure in some model under the assumption that the key is kept secure. So my first expectation is to find out if there are formal models or definitions of secret that can be proven. However, it is clearly a problem that depends on a lot of variables. My question aims to find out if there is a framework to compare alternatives or if the decision depends on the luck of the analyst (guided by best practices models, yes, but in practice one must often compromise, and finding criteria to prioritize controls is my aim).

Comment: I think the most secure way to store the cryptographic keys is using Hardware security module. Maybe by evaluating the security of the HSM devices you can measure the assumption that the key is securely stored

Comment: And usually they put a lot of emphasis on their FIPS 140/Common Criteria certifications. What I am wondering is if there is to build a more solid argument than "it is an industry standard, and therefore it is good" (I feel it too close to a falacy). For instance, if I were to say "store a key in a smart card of (specific model) is as safe as storing it in an HSM (specific model)" could there be better reasons than "both are FIPS 140 level 3 certified"? I feel certifications please managers, but leave technical people with some level of doubt.

Comment: @SergioAndrésFigueroaSantos Perhaps not true in this instance, but my general feeling about certifications is that they exist primarily to make money for the issuer.

Comment: I'd say the danger lies mostly on taking them as holy undisputable truth. They could be a compass towards a right direction, but what I am looking for are tools to agree with (or dismiss) their reasoning.

Comment: There are various methodologies for quantitative risk assessment (e.g. [this](http://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/auditing/quantitative-risk-analysis-step-by-step-849)). I am pretty sceptical about their usefulness; in infosec there are so many unknowns. Also, you are estimating a "long tail" of unlikely events, so small uncertainties have a large impact. I would advise you to use a qualitative methodology instead. Start by thinking about what realistic options you have for key storage.

Comment: @SergioAndrésFigueroaSantos: You are right about the FIPS 140 doubt part. USB-Sticks had been tested and certified for FIPS140 ... but only for the implementation of the crypto-algorithm. They did not certify the USB-Sticks as a whole. Result: [FIPS140-Sticks send the same 32 bytes after a sucessful login](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2010/01/fips_140-2_leve.html) ... making them very easy to crack by sending those 32 bytes yourself. Therefore certifications or absolute numbers (as proposed here) make little sense, since they wont reflect the whole picture imho.

Comment: So, basically, it only makes sense to evaluate specific controls and attack vectors, probably qualitatively, to determine its quality? Would that be guided by a mixture of good practices, instinct and hoping that nothing too bad is ignored?

Comment: Sounds about right - and a little bit sad. But I think it won't be possible to create an "additive list" that contains things adding to security. I.e. "HMS +1, FIPS 140 certified +0.75, ...". It should be more like: "Is the system secure?" and if you find a flaw the answer is "No". If you want to have more degrees of security, you could create a "Probability / Impact"-graph: How probable is a certain attack or error to occur and how big would the impact be? If an attack is very unlikely and has a low impact: **ignore**. If the attack is very likely and has a high impact: **system is flawed**.

Comment: Another view might be, that you try to verify a certain algorithm / system, which is hard to impossible to do. Instead you actually want to falsify it, trying to find flaws, errors and bugs until you find no more.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if there will be a nice answer to this question. There are formal methods (formal verification tools) that you can validate whether your protocol satisfy some properties under some assumptions. Thus, you can mark your (key management) protocol safe. Still, you have three question remain. (1) What were the assumptions? (2) Is the model I tested really map the actual key management protocol? (3) Even in that case, is the verification tool safe, correct and sound?

Even after formal verification, you generally end up with binary results such as safe/unsafe.